# slice spaing in rsFMRI

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, fmri

I have a rsFMRI sequence that includes **slice spacing**. I have not seen that before. Why anybody would add slice spacing between 2 measured slices?
Is it a mistake or there is a rationale behind, eg incr. SNR?

Slice Thickness  2.6
Slice Spacing 0.5

Thanks,